# Can YAML Front Matter be inherited in jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll

Is it possible to inherit YAML Front Matter in a jekyll site? I would like to add variables at a directory level, so that all pages in that directory have the variables, without having to add them individually.

Comment: Can you share any code you have tried or any errors you have gotten while trying?  That will help people answer your question.

Comment: I don't really have any code, just a directory structure. It would help me if all of the files in the /vehicle directory would automatically have either category or tag "vehicle". More stuff would be nice, if possible, like cascading _config.yml files in subdirectories below the root.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [front matter defaults](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults).

### Directory structure example

> It would help me if all of the files in the /vehicle directory would
>   automatically have either category or tag "vehicle".

Add this to config.yml:

```
defaults:
- scope:
    path: vehicle
  values:
    category: vehicle
```

### Extras

> More stuff would be nice, if possible, like cascading _config.yml
>   files in subdirectories below the root.

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to cascade an entire `_config.yml` file. However, you should be able to cascade front matter defaults.